# Need help with FEA bar analysis problem

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, applied-mechanics, structures, finite-element-method

I'm trying to solve this
 [image: problem] 
which is to find the total deformation of the bar.

I'm trying to implement the finite element approach, but I am getting way too large of numbers. Here is what I did in Excel.

[image]

I thought my units were wrong, but they seem to be fine. The only difference from the other problem I solved was that the second boundary condition was supported; this one has a free end.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If looks like you made a typo entering some of the numbers in the spreadsheet. (We don't do your homework here, so find it yourself!)

Comment: Note that while excel is probably worlds most used programming environment, its also the hardest to debug in.

Comment: @joojaa Well, debugging this particular error is trivial for anyone with normal vision. Neither the question nor the answer has anything much to do with finite element analysis though.

Comment: Look for a place where you have used a negative sign instead of a positive sign.  Also, keep in mind that the stiffness has a physical meaning and should have values which are reasonable.